# exception with cassandra cluster name mismatch

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Previously, I had a node belonging to cluster A. Side by Side, I had cluster B running too. After few weeks, I tore down cluster A, cleared up all its state. But when I am trying to add this node to cluster B, it throws exception saved name cluster A != configured name cluster B.

In past, clearing the state for a node and adding it to different cluster, always worked with me. This is the first time, I have seen this issue. Can someone help me debug, where can this state of old cluster be persisted?

Answer (score 0):

I expect the issue to be the cluster_name in the cassandra.yaml configuration.

The node from cluster A probably has a cluster_name different from the nodes in cluster B

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to cleanup all the files present in  /var/lib/cassandra directory.

You can keep the folders present in /var/lib/cassandra/ but clean everything inside those folders.

This should fix your issue.